# method 'withConverter' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'

Tags: flutter, firebase

Why  i am getting htis error

"The method 'withConverter' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'withConverter'."

```
  final productsRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').withConverter<Product>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Product.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
        toFirestore: (products, _) => products.toJson(),
      );
```

I am quite sure it was working few days back , any update . What is the alternative ?